# Web Api C# - Task.Factory.startnew vs async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, logging, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing logging within my endpoints where the logs are sent to a separate service.  I don't want the overhead of sending the logs to a service to affect to service that the client is consuming and I don't care if logs sometimes don't make it. Therefore I've been reading blogs about how to simple fire and forget. I get that CPU intensive tasks should not use async but I don't see how IO related tasks are any different, by IO I mean an endpoint that calls another service, in this case for the purpose of logging.

Also I seem to be getting conflicting views.  Some blogs say you should never run anything async because this simply takes one or more threads from the threadpool and it's therefore no different than doing it synchronized.

Microsoft introduced the async and await keywords into .Net 4.5 which they say you should use for the entire endpoint but doesn't this still use one or more threads from the thread pool?.  And finally some stackoverflow posts I've read say that it's fine to use Task.Factory.StartNew because .Net will manage it.

Could someone please clarify the above in terms of best practice sending logs to another service as I am very confused.

I'm considering using nlog because of its batching and async features but again I'm not sure if this is the best way.  I cannot use something like Hangfire because I don't have sql backend.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, a bit of homework for you: What's the difference between synchronous and asynchronous IO? What advantage does using asynchronous IO give you over synchronous IO? What part do IO Completion Ports (IOCP) play in this and how do they free up CPU resources when waiting on IO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Some blogs say you should never run anything async because this simply takes one or more threads from the threadpool

No, that's absolutely not true. `async` does not use threadpool threads. (For more information, see my blog post [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)).

> And finally some stackoverflow posts I've read say that it's fine to use Task.Factory.StartNew because .Net will manage it.

Again, not true. `StartNew` is a dangerous API and should never be used this way. (For more information, see my blog post [`StartNew` Is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)).

> Therefore I've been reading blogs about how to simple fire and forget.

Since you "don't care if logs sometimes don't make it", then I'd recommend using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`. QBWI will not *prevent* logs from being lost, but it will do its best to *minimize* log loss. Just throwing work onto the thread pool using `Task.Run` (or the outdated and dangerous `StartNew`) will not even *try* to minimize loss of logs. Hangfire is for when you need something more robust - if you *required* your logs to be correct, e.g., for billing or auditing. (For more information, see my blog post on [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)).

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is very clear, I'll ready your blog posts.